# Related res_partner in odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

Why is the name field missing from XML in odoo 12 and I can't edit it now.  In odoo 10 this code worker fine. Maybe some access rights have disappeared after the update?

**All fields that are made through related disappeared from the views**. Not only the field from the example below was missing

Example :

MODEL :

```
partner = fields.Many2one('res.partner', required=True, ondelete='restrict')
name = fields.Char(related='partner.name', string='Resident Name', store=True,
track_visibility='onchange')
```

XML FIELD :

```
<field name="name" required="1"/>
```

Comment: in the related field add one more argument readonly=False and try it it will work for you

Comment: what is the error message